# Transit Option not working in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a requirement to create an application which would show public transport routes between a source and a destination which i acheived it successfully. But i found that the transit routes does not seem to work for most of the cities. It works for only a few places. For Eg: I selected source ***Mumbai*** and destination as ***Bangalore***. I get the result as zero results found but in fact there are trains and buses between the routes.
The API i am using is mentioned below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Is there any other alternate API that i can use? Any solution that can tackle this issue..Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Google Transit doesn't have coverage for all cities/countries. You can check it out here:
[Google Maps Transit](https://www.google.com/intl/en/landing/transit/)

From this page you can access all cities that are covered by Google Transit. If you search for itinerary from Mumbai to Bangalore, it will open maps and you will see the following message:

> Sorry, your search appears to be outside our current coverage area for
>   transit. Get driving directions

I hope this helps

Comment: Any chance you've observed a situation where the option is greyed out in just one city that is supposed to have coverage? Any ideas as to why that might happen? I am seeing that currently with Salt Lake City, Utah, for example.